# React :getting offsetTop value and accessing the DOM dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am currently working on a react app,
and I need to implement changes on the screen that occurs when an element is on a certain position on the screen (on certain offsetTopValue), 
this should be done dynamically because every element has a unique id that is created dynamically. 
(it also contains 3 purecompenets and 2 functional components down the hierarchy
 and most props are passed down using context)

**index.jsx**

```
class Collection extends Component {
     <CollectionContext.Provider
      value={{state: this.state, cards: this.props.cards...}}>
      .......
      ideal: (
        <CollectionLayout cards= {this.props.cards ..../>
        .......
        </CollectionContext.Provider>
       }
```

**layout.jsx**

```
componentDidMount () {
  this._bindScroll();
}
_handleScroll = () => {
  var html = document.documentElement;
  this.updateCardsPositions();
}
render(
  ...
return(
    <CollectionContext.Consumer>
    {context =>
    <Loader
    randomSpin= {this.props.randomSpin}
    currentTopic = {this.props.currentTopic}
  />}
   <CollectionContext.Consumer>
 );
)
```

**loader.jsx**

```
export const Loader = ({ randomSpin, currentTopic}) => (
.....
  {!context.state.spinning &&
    context.cards.map((card, index) => <Card key={index} card=
{card}/>)}
```

**cards.jsx**

```
export const Card = ({ card } **id={card.id}**) => {
   return (...);
}
```

what I do have: I have a unique card id that is passed to each card, 
and I can access the cards id in the layout.

I tried  using refs but am not yet sure about the proper way
to pass it through all those components and access it in ComponentDidMount()
in the layout.

I tried utilizing the context but it can be accessed only inside render and not on componentDidMount.

I am also not sure how should I use the refs callback: 
({(el)=>{inputRef = el}}) with a dynamic value (every card has a unique id that should be refed.

any other suggestions on how to get the offset top values from the layout would help.

I will appreciate any help or a general solution direction with it.

Thank You!